# SQLite3 rows not being inserted first time script is run

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a problem with sqlite in python on an Ubuntu machine. I run a few loops that insert data into a sqlite3 database. the first loop inserts both into the students and addresses table and the last one inserts only into the addresses table.

The problem seems to be that the last loop doesn't add more than a record or two to the db the first time it is run, any subsequent time it is run it works perfectly. I have tried this multiple times by deleting the db and running the script once, checking the data, then running the script again.

I was wondering if this might be due to the volume of data I am adding to the db.

I have provided a highlight of the code below:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
conn.text_factory = str
for file in directory:
    studentNo,surname,Address = getFromFile(file)
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO Students (StudentNumber,Surname) VALUES (?,?);", (studentNo,surname));
    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT ID from Students WHERE StudentNumber = '" + studentNo + "';")
    for row in cursor:
        conn.execute("INSERT INTO Addresses (StudentID,Address) VALUES (?, ?);", (row[0], Address));
        break
conn.commit()

#insert more stuff through similar loops, each one of these loops runs about 15000 times
# ...
# every other loop except the following appear to work well enough

for file in directory:
    studentNo, address = getDataFromAlternativeSource(file)

    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT ID from Students WHERE StudentNumber = '" + studentNo + "';")
    for row in cursor:
        conn.execute("INSERT INTO Addresses (StudentID,Address) VALUES (?, ?);", (row[0], address));
        break
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

If more details are need, please drop a comment below

Comment: Why do you have `break` statements inside both those for loops?

Comment: To only execute for the top and probably only result, I personally think it looks neater than ``.fetchone()[0]``

Comment: It does not look neater, it's just confusing (as evidenced by the fact that you confused a talented and experienced programmer).  It's also less efficient than using LIMIT in the SELECT statement and less correct than using LIMIT *and* ORDER BY to produce replicable results or checking for multiple results and throwing an Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code you've shown us, the problem most likely is that `getDataFromAlternativeSource(file)` is returning a `studentNo` value that is not what you think it is -- and is not present in the `Students` table.  That would cause the `SELECT` to return nothing and your loop would never execute -- a silent failure mode.

Without at least a description of what you're trying to accomplish with `getFromFile()` and `getDataFromAlternativeSource()` it's hard to guess what you expect to see added to the database.

In any event, it's difficult if not impossible to overwhelm SQLite with a large amount of data, and certainly the relatively small number of records that could be produced on a one-record-per-file basis on almost any existing file system.

Answer (score -1):

You have "Address" and "address" that's ok?

I don't know the meaning of the inserts but you can try to do something like this:

```
try:
    with con:
        con.execute("INSERT INTO Addresses (StudentID,Address) VALUES (?, ?);", (row[0], Address))
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    print "couldn't add the same address twice"
```

maybe if the address is already in the database, the insert statement don't produce any results.